# Simple Python Syntax Error (Indentation/Whitespace)

Tags: python, syntax, whitespace, indentation

```
def project_to_distance(point_x, point_y, distance):
    dist_to_origin = math.square_root(point_x ** 2 + point_y ** 2)    
        scale = distance / dist_to_origin
    print point_x * scale, point_y * scale

project_to_distance(2, 7, 4)
```

I get the following error on the scale line (shown below). Can anyone please advise what this pertains to?

```
SyntaxError: bad input ('        ')
```

Comment: Why is the line `scale = distance / dist_to_origin` indented more than the lines before and after?

Comment: I fixed it. Thanks so much. How do I upvote you?

Comment: @user2603139 You can't upvote comments till you have more reputation.

Comment: This is from an on-line course in coursera.org.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code.

Here is the revised code I've provided for you:

```
import math

def project_to_distance(point_x, point_y, distance):
    dist_to_origin = math.sqrt(point_x ** 2 + point_y ** 2)    
    scale = distance / dist_to_origin
    return point_x * scale, point_y * scale

print project_to_distance(2, 7, 4)
```

- **Why is "import math" included?** On the off-chance you don't know about importing, you need to include the `math` module in order to use advanced functions.
- **Where is my square_root?** `math.square_root()` does not exist- the function you mean to call is `math.sqrt()`.
- **Why did I get `SyntaxError: bad input ('        ')`?** Because in Python, whitespace (indents) are considered part of the syntax, so that programs in Python are always easier to read. You have the line `scale = distance / dist_to_origin` indented too far, and it confuses the Python compiler.
- **Why did you change `print` to `return` at the end of `project_to_distance()`?** This is a higher programming concept -- early excercises teach you to `print` so that you can see your results, but unfortunately it confuses the subject of `returning` a value. Normally, you would put `return` at the end of a function because you don't *always* want to print. For example, `math.sqrt()` is a function just like `project_to_distance()`. Only, it does not `print`, it calculates and `returns` the value. Relate `project_to_distance()` to `sqrt()` and you will understand why `return` is more valuable.
- **Why did you add `print` to the end of the code?** Because now that your function `returns`, assuming you want it to print, you have to tell it to. But now, when you run a program, you can run `project_to_distance` and use it as a tool in later work, rather than an always-printing function.

Happy coding.

Bonus: [Here is an amazing Python tutorial](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/python)

Answer (score 4):

I see a couple of issues:

1. Indentation of `scale = distance / dist_to_origin`
2. `math.square_root` does not exist, it is `math.sqrt`

Code:

```
import math

def project_to_distance(point_x, point_y, distance):
    dist_to_origin = math.sqrt(point_x ** 2 + point_y ** 2)    
    scale = distance / dist_to_origin
    print point_x * scale, point_y * scale

project_to_distance(2, 7, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

It works fine for me when I write the following :

```
def project_to_distance(point_x, point_y, distance):
    dist_to_origin = math.sqrt(point_x ** 2 + point_y ** 2)    
    scale = distance / dist_to_origin
    print point_x * scale, point_y * scale

project_to_distance(2, 7, 4)
```

Do not intent scale.

Comment: I appreciate the help guys. I'm going to vote for David Robinson since he jumped in first. Can someone advise how to do that?

Comment: @user2603139 He only commented, which doesn't really count.  You can only accept answers.  Besides, @jabaldonedo fixed the `sqrt` thing as well, so he fixed all your issues.

Comment: @Davlov Did this really work?  `math.square_root` doesn't exist.  You should have gotten an `AttributeError`

Comment: I know - I figured that part afterwards.

Comment: @SethMMorton Sorry, I did that automatically. I thought he already imported it.

Comment: @user2603139 yeah, it is. I get tons of errors when inteding wrong.

Comment: you have to add import math at the top - then use math.sqrt

Comment: @user2603139 When you vote for an answer, please make sure to vote for the one that helps you the *most*, not who jumps in first. Some people will come back and give you better answers after you've already picked one, so you can change it. The point of picking a best answer is for people who come after you do, and have the same problem. Find the best answer that helped you and might help them, too. :)

Comment: @Davlog is it python or coduskulptor - sorry your comment confused me at the end

Comment: @user2603139 Read my post, it will explain the Python indentation thing :)